# Establish trust relationship for secure web service using SetCertificatePolicy()

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've written a .NET application in C# that contacts a few web services. Everything works fine when I reference the web services on a non-secure URL; but when I reference the same web services on a secure HTTPS URL, I get an exception with the message "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

I was pointed to at this web page http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel-with-authority.html. And added the code to my application. This resolves the issue and I can now use the secure web services as expected.

I notice the code snippet above says "not intended to be used in a production environment" and it currently trusts any certificate. In order to make it more secure for a production environment, should I be checking it for our own certificate? How should I check this, the 'cert' parameter in the method RemoteCertificateValidate() has a lot of information in it so I'm not sure how or what I should be checking.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely there is a problem with the certificate used by the server to identity itself when your client is establishing the secure SSL connection. In my experience this is primarily caused by the certificate that the server returns is either not signed by a trusted root authority or one or more certificates in the chain is not valid (e.g. they have expired or are for a domain other than the one you are connecting to).

To help identify the problem you could try browsing to the service endpoint URL and seeing whether the browser reports any issues. Modern browsers will warn you if a server certificate is not valid and will sometimes tell you why. If you are using Chrome and there is a problem with the certificate you will see a red cross through the padlock icon at the left end of the address bar (or omnibox). If you click on the padlock Chrome will tell you why it doesn't like the certificate.

As for the code snippet you found, this is an example of how to implement validation of server certificates as a client in .Net. However, the example itself will never reject a connection to the server even if there is a problem with the servers certificate, hence the comment about not using the code in production. Outside of a test scenario you never want to be communicating with a server who's identity you cannot trust due to a bad certificate. To provide a "production" implementation you must check the value of the "error" parameter to see if there are any problems with the certificate and only return true if there are none.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Attach my certificate validation delegate.
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.google.com");
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }

        private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
        {
            if (error == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I am only returning true from my ServerCertificateValidationCallback delegate if the value of error is equal to SslPolicyErrors.None, otherwise I return false which generates an exception. To make this example work I used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to proxy the request and return an untrusted certificate to my client code. If you navigate to https://www.google.com under normal conditions you should **not** see any certificate errors as Google plays nice!!

PKI with certificates can be a gnarly domain to work in. In terms of documentation [Wikipedia has a good article on PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) that covers how trusted authorities are used to sign certificates used in SSL so that clients can trust the identity of a server they are communicating with.